# Selenium Unable to locate element (Python) WebScraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a real estate website for listings. It has an aspx form that has to filled out before submission.

http://www.cbre.us/PropertyListings/Pages/Properties-for-Sale.aspx

All I care about is multifamily properties in Oregon, however.  So this was my first attempt:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("http://www.cbre.us/PropertyListings/Pages/Properties-for-Sale.aspx")

#Searching for multifamily residences
selectPropertyType = driver.find_element_by_id("ForSalePropertyType")
selectPropertyType.select_by_value("70")

#In the state of Oregon
selectState = driver.find_element_by_id("ForSaleState_ListBox1")
selectState.select_by_value("OR")

#Submit form
submitBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("ForSaleLooplinkSubmit")
submitBtn.click()

#Wait for results to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
```

When I run this script it gives an error "Can't locate element "ForSalePropertyType".  What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This element located inside an `iframe`. You have to *switch to it's context*:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_IFrameContent_IFrameContent")

# searching for multifamily residences
selectPropertyType = driver.find_element_by_id("ForSalePropertyType")
selectPropertyType.select_by_value("70")
```

To get back to default context:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

---

As a side note, be aware of the policies listed in the [Disclaimer / Terms of use](http://www.cbre.us/Pages/legal/disclaimer.aspx), specifically:

> **You agree that you will not**: (a) impersonate any person or entity or
>   misrepresent your affiliation with any other person or entity; **(b)
>   engage in spamming, flooding, harvesting of e-mail addresses or other
>   personal information, spidering, screen scraping, database scraping,
>   or any other activity with the purpose of obtaining lists of users or
>   any other information, including specifically, property listings
>   available through the site;** (c) send chain letters or pyramid schemes
>   via the site; or (d) attempt to gain unauthorized access to other
>   computer systems through the site. You agree that you will not use the
>   site in any manner that could damage, disable, overburden, or impair
>   the site or interfere with any other party's use and enjoyment of the
>   site.

Comment: Duly noted.  Thank you for your help.