# Selenium won't click a button with python?

Tags: python, selenium

please can someone help me with this,

I can't get selenium to click a button with python. I'm on python 3.4 and using Firefox 42

the browser opens but that's all

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")
elem = find_element_by_id_name("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

The browser opens but i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ro/sele.py", line 6, in <module>
    elem = find_element_by_id_name("selectfilebox")
NameError: name 'find_element_by_id_name' is not defined
```

Comment: This isn't a selenium problem, it's a problem with your Python imports. You need to tell Python how to find the `find_element_by_id_name` function.

Comment: right ok thanks, i'm sorry if I sound like a noob but did you mean elem = driver.find_element_by_name ?

Comment: Something like that. I don't know which module that function is in, I'll leave it up to you to find out.

Comment: You can take a look at the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) section 4.1(for locating an element by id).

Comment: There is 'find_element_by_id_name()'  function in python, it may be either 'find_element_by_id()' or 'find_element_by_name()'. You should use any one of these based on requirement.

Answer (score 6):

It helps to inspect `driver.page_source` to see the HTML *as the driver sees it*.

```
driver.get("http://www.speedyshare.com/")
content = driver.page_source
with open('/tmp/out', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

You'll see in /tmp/out:

```
<frameset rows="*"><frame src="http://www30.speedyshare.com/upload_page.php" name="index31" />
</frameset>
```

Aha. The tag you wish to click is inside a frame. So switch to that frame first:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("index31")
```

and then you'll be able to find the element by id:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("selectfilebox")
elem.click()
```

This question is essentially the same as [Selenium Unable to locate element (Python) WebScraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32636453/190597); it's just hard to know that without first knowing the solution.

Comment: Thanks for this, you really went in depth and it was very insightful, sorry I've took my time to reply but I wanted to get it working and not bug anyone to be spoonfed the info. I've come up with this but it's still not working.

Comment: The idea of looking at page source is great.