# How take XPATH inside a iframe?

Tags: selenium, iframe, xpath

Im trying to get the XPATH inside a iframe called "gadget_6" [image: called "gadget_6"]

i need the xpath of select div. Using selenium i do:

```
self.change_frame('__gadget_6') #Change to the correct iframe
```

after that, i try to do:

```
self.selec_orgvdc = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div')
```

for posteriorly do:

```
self.selec_orgvdc.click
```

but i obtain the error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Someone can help me?

New modification:

```
self.change_frame('__gadget_6')
time.sleep(4)
self.logger.info("Buscando orgvdc")
#self.selec_orgvdc = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.GN4Y2ATIMD table div.gwt-Label')
self.selec_orgvdc = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div')
self.logger.info("Encontrado!")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Unable to locate element (Python) WebScraping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636453/selenium-unable-to-locate-element-python-webscraping)

Answer (score 2):

Hi to work with xpath inside iframe first you have to sitch your driver instance ti that iframe then only you can perform any action

```
1.To switch to an iframe plz do it like : driver.switchTo().frame("selfservice");
```

Also looking at your source code i can clearly see there is 2 (two) i frames

1.iframe id = __gadget_6
2.iframe id = selfservice

hence i can guess why its not working in your case cause you are switching to a wrong i frame

now try this **xpath** `//*[@class='GN4Y2ATIMD']/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div` to perform click this will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

XPath shouldn't include the /html/body.  try this:

```
self.selec_orgvdc = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div')
```

Note that this will be quite brittle.  Even better would be to do something like this CSS:

```
self.selec_orgvdc = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS,'div.GN4Y2ATIMD table div.gwt-Label')
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Witt the solution(applied in the section new modification of my edited post) i have the error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[5]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div"}

Comment: See?  Brittle.  It looks like it should be div[4] not div[5] from your image.