# Xpath for table - List having multiple tr and td - find first element and click on checkbox

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm struggling with xpath issues. The code is contained in an iframe which is being handled:

```
<div _ngcontent-c10 class="panel panel-info">
  <div _ngcontent-c10 class="panel-heading"> ABC Output </div>
<div _ngcontent-c10 class="panel-body">
<form _ngcontent-c10 novalidate class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
<div _ngcontent-c10 class="row">
<table _ngcontent-c10 class="table tb-striped">
<tbody _ngcontent-c10>
<tr _ngcontent-c10="">
          <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-35">
           <label _ngcontent-c10="">
               <input _ngcontent-c10="" type="checkbox" value="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
           </label>
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-20 no-side-padding">
           <img _ngcontent-c10="" class="outputLogo" src="https://qa-server/Services/content/logos/AAAA1.png" alt="AAA1">
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-text-bold">
           AAA1 Output
           <!---->
       </td>
</tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c10="">
          <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-35">
           <label _ngcontent-c10="">
               <input _ngcontent-c10="" type="checkbox" value="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
           </label>
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-20 no-side-padding">
           <img _ngcontent-c10="" class="outputLogo" src="https://qa-server/Services/content/logos/BBB1.png" alt="BBB1">
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-text-bold">
           BBB1 Output
           <!---->
       </td>
</tr>
<tr _ngcontent-c10="">
          <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-35">
           <label _ngcontent-c10="">
               <input _ngcontent-c10="" type="checkbox" value="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
           </label>
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-fixed-width-20 no-side-padding">
           <img _ngcontent-c10="" class="outputLogo" src="https://qa-server/Services/content/logos/CCC1.png" alt="CCC1">
       </td>
       <td _ngcontent-c10="" class="td-text-bold">
           CCC1 Output
           <!---->
       </td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to find the first row in the list to click on Checkbox, these are the ones I tried already:

```
webElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'AAA1 Output')]//preceding::label/input[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][@type='checkbox']"));

webElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[.,'AAA1 Output')]//preceding::label/input[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][@type='checkbox']"));

webElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'AAA1 Output')]//preceding::input[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][@type='checkbox']"));

webElement = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[.,'AAA1 Output')]//preceding::input[@class='ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid'][@type='checkbox']"));

webElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='panel panel-info']//following::tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]"));

webElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//[contains(.,'ABC Output']//following::tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]"));
```

However, they can not click on checkbox for first element.

Comment: [1][1] And maybe this two topics may help [How take XPATH inside a iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568726/how-take-xpath-inside-a-iframe) & [Selenium Unable to locate element (Python) WebScraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636453/selenium-unable-to-locate-element-python-webscraping)

Comment: And this one is for checkbox,- [w3 Tutorial Page](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp), and this by DOM,- `document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;`

Comment: Can you update the Question with the `HTML` including the `<iframe>` tag & your code block where you handle `switching to the iframe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you the first `tr` in the table with class `'table tb-striped'`

```
//table[@class='table tb-striped']/tbody/tr[1]
```

If you want to select the row based on the content, for example `AAA1 Output`, you can use:

```
//tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]
```

Let's say you want to get the first `td` from the `tr` that contains the text `AAA1 Output`, you can use the following:

```
//tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]
```

And to get the checkbox inside this `td`, use this:

```
//tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']
```

To click on this checkbox, use

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']")).Click();
```

Just make sure you switched to the iframe before attempting to click the checkbox. You can switch to a frame using the following lines

```
// Find frame by its index (this is zero based)
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

// Find frame by string (name or id)
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("firstFrame");

// Find frame by web element
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(myFrameElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry I missed the one vital part of this issue. I want to click on checkbox and your solution is not working as well. Example : OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: //table[@class='table table-striped']/tbody/tr[1]'

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'Unable to locate element: //tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']'

Comment: Did you switch to the iframe?

Comment: Yes , your this "//table[@class='table tb-striped']/tbody/tr[1]" worked for me only if I use this xpath in method directly. But If I use this xpath in page class and try to return this, it's not working for wired reason. Please Suggest.

Comment: Do you get an error? Can you share your page class for me?

Comment: this is workign for me : 
Addout.cs

public static void CheckAAA1()
        {
webElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[contains(., 'AAA! Output')]/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']"));
webElement.Click();
}
------------------------------
if I return same above webElement from page.cs , it's not working 
page.cs 

  public static IWebElement CheckAAA1()
        {
            webElement = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[contains(., 'AAA1 Output')]/td[1]//input[@type='checkbox']"));
            return webElement;
        }

Comment: Do you call both methods from the same page in the same iframe?

Comment: there are two classes 1. Addout.cs , 2 page.cs // Addout.cs is a kind of Module class I am writing all logic here. I am returning "webelment" from page.cs to Addout.cs.  I am calling iFrame from another (third )class.