# Extract coordinates from a embed google maps with popup in R

Tags: r, google-maps, web-scraping, coordinates, rvest

I'd like to catch these coordinates using R webscraping tool:

[image]

This is what I'm trying just coping the xpath where the coordinates are in the page but doing so xpath catch nothing.

```
html <- 'https://guiaempresas.universia.es/LOGISTICA-EGA.html'
x <- tryCatch(expr= {read_html(htmls)}, error=function(e){NA})
xpath <- '//*[@id="mapDiv"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]'
xx <- x %>% html_nodes(xpath = xpath)
```

This is what returns:

> xx
> {xml_nodeset (0)}

Whats is the method to do so in R?

Comment: The problem is maybe the div is inside a iframe. 
You should find out how to switch to that document with your tool. I found this when using Selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37591904/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the decimal values easily as follows. Then use a package like `celestial` to format in `dms` as desired.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)
library(celestial)

page <- read_html('https://guiaempresas.universia.es/LOGISTICA-EGA.html')

lat <- page %>% html_node('.latitude .value-title') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()
lon <- page %>% html_node('.longitude .value-title') %>% html_text() %>% as.numeric()

# https://rdrr.io/cran/celestial/man/deg2dms.html

print(deg2dms(lat, type='cat', sep='dms', digits=1))
print(deg2dms(lon, type='cat', sep='dms', digits=1))
```