# Python Selenium using onclick

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium in python and cannot get it to find and select the ok button. Here is the code I am trying to use that is not finding the button.

```
SubmitElem = driver.find_element_by_name('ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$RptControls$btnOK')

SubmitElem.submit()
```

And this is the webpage code

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$RptControls$btnOK" 
value="OK" 
onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$RptControls$btnOK&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))"      
id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_RptControls_btnOK" accesskey="o"   
class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" type="submit">
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong? I found some suggestions to add `onclick*=` but it did not seem to work.

Comment: If the element is inside a frame, you first have to switch context to that frame: See [Selenium Unable to locate element (Python) WebScraping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32636453/190597).

Answer (score 3):

As noted earlier, if the element is in an iframe, you need to [switch contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636613/1793198). Additionally, if the element takes time to show up on the DOM, due to it being dynamically rendered by JavaScript, you might need [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html). You basically want to wait until the element shows up on the page before performing actions on it.

From the Selenium docs:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per the HTML you have provided, you may consider the following options:

1. You can consider to construct a `xpath` based on `name` as follows:

   ```
   SubmitElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl01$RptControls$btnOK']")
   SubmitElem.submit()
   ```
2. You can also try a different `xpath` based on `id` as follows:

   ```
   SubmitElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01_RptControls_btnOK']")
   SubmitElem.submit()
   ```
3. Alternatively, you can also consider to call `click()` method instead of `submit()` method.

   ```
   SubmitElem.click()
   ```
4. Again, it seems to me that the `id` and `name` is dynamic due to presence of JavaScript and AJAX Calls. In that case you can consider to  construct a dynamic `xpath` as follows:

   ```
   SubmitElem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00')]")
   SubmitElem.submit()
   ```
5. You can consider to  construct a dynamic `css_selector` as follows:

   ```
   SubmitElem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id^='ctl00']")
   SubmitElem.submit()
   ```
6. Finally, if you see a `NoSuchElementException` or `ElementNotVisibleException` you may consider to induce some `WebDriverWait` as follows:

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@name, 'ctl00')]")))
   driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name^='ctl00']").click()
   ```

> There are total **6** suggested locators to identify the element along with different other options.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.